# Laravel failed to load the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my controller

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        //echo $users->count();
        //exit;
        return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

as you see I already tried to check the count of the `users` variable and the result is 2

In my `views` folder I have these folders:

```
users
    index.blade.php
layouts
    users.blade.php
```

This is my `index.blade.php`

```
@section('main')

<h1>All Users</h1>

<p>{{ link_to_route('users.create', 'Add new user') }}</p>

@if ($users->count())
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->password }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit',
 array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}</td>
                    <td>
          {{ Form::open(array('method' 
=> 'DELETE', 'route' => array('users.destroy', $user->id))) }}                       
                            {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class'
 => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>

    </table>
@else
    There are no users
@endif

@stop
```

and this is my `users.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap
/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            table form { margin-bottom: 0; }
            form ul { margin-left: 0; list-style: none; }
            .error { color: red; font-style: italic; }
            body { padding-top: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            @if (Session::has('message'))
                <div class="flash alert">
                    <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
                </div>
            @endif

            @yield('main')
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

When I request this url `http://localhost:8082/laravel/public/users` I got an empty page.

Though if I change the content of `index.blade.php` to `test test`, I got `test test` in my browser.

What am I missing please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't mention anywhere in your users/index template that you want to extend the layouts/users file. Add this line to the top, that should be enough:

```
@extends('layouts.users')
```